# Ada: polymorphic callbacks

Tags: design-patterns, ada

I'm trying to implement an Observer pattern using OOP and dynamic dispatching, but I'm not able to create an access-to-subprogram constant because the argument types of the named access and the procedure of the type extension don't match.

I provide a minimal reproducibable example, ommiting subscription:

```
package Alarms is

  type time_t is mod 2**32;

  type AlarmObserver_t is interface;
  type Callback_t is access procedure (this : in out AlarmObserver_t);

  type AlarmPublisher_t (<>) is tagged limited private;
  function fConstructor (capacity : in Positive) return AlarmPublisher_t;

private

  type AlarObserverAcc_t is access AlarmObserver_t'Class;

  type dummy_t is new AlarmObserver_t with null record;
  procedure pEventDummy (this : in out dummy_t) is Null;

  dummy : constant AlarObserverAcc_t := new dummy_t;
  dummyCallback : constant Callback_t := pEventDummy'Access; --Fails

  type Node_t is limited
    record
      Observer : AlarObserverAcc_t := dummy;
      Callback : Callback_t := dummyCallback;
      time : time_t := time_t'Last;
    end record;

  defaultNode : constant Node_t := Node_t' (Observer => dummy,
                                            Callback => dummyCallback,
                                            time     => time_t'Last);

  type ObserverArray_t is array (Positive range <>) of Node_t;

  type AlarmPublisher_t (capacity : Positive) is tagged limited 
    record
      --Member "observers" has default initialisation because Node_t is initialised
      observers : ObserverArray_t (Positive'First .. capacity);
    end record;

end Alarms;
```

And the implementation to let you reproduce it:

```
package body Alarms is
  
  function fConstructor (capacity : in Positive) return AlarmPublisher_t is
  begin
    return Obj : AlarmPublisher_t (capacity => capacity) do
      Null;
    end return;
  end fConstructor;

end Alarms;
```

I was inspiring in [Matthew Heaney callbacks Observer pattern](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Patterns&CID=291)

He use a class-wide argument for the access-to-subprogram procedure, but I would like to use OOP notation and let the concrete observers to have those procedures as primitives.

Why procedure pEventDummy is not compatible if dummy_t implements AlarmObserver_t interface?
Can I do what I want?

I provide an example below to show what I would like to do. I want concrete observers to be flexible and allow them to subscribe to the method they want to be notified when the subscribed alarm expires. I don't know in advance which primitives will be used for that purpose so I don't want to type all the possibilities as abstract primitives of the AlarmObserver_t interface, I would like let the concrete observers to subscribe to an access to procedure for that purpose, and they will be notified through them at different moments:

```
with Alarms;

package ConcreteObserver is

  type ConcreteObserver_t is new Alarms.AlarmObserver_t with private;

  --Procedure evTimeout to be notified for an alarm expirancy.
  --Null implementation to let you compile
  procedure evTimeout (this : in out ConcreteObserver_t) is null;

  --Procedure evAnotherTimeout to be notified for another alarm expirancy
  --Null implementation to let you compile
  procedure evAnotherTimeout (this : in out ConcreteObserver_t) is null;

private

  --This will fail as dummyCallback in Alarms package
  evTimeoutCallback : constant Alarms.Callback_t := evTimeout'Access; 

  --This will fail as dummyCallback in Alarms package
  evAnotherTimeoutCallback : constant Alarms.Callback_t := evAnotherTimeout'Access; 

  type ConcreteObserver_t is new Alarms.AlarmObserver_t with 
    record
      --Any attribute
      Null;
    end record;


end ConcreteObserver;
```

Comment: I can make the callback argument as class-wide and then implement a compliant wrapper procedure to downcast and perform the dispatching call, but it's a bit annoying and I don't like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding a polymorphic operation to your interface type:

```ada
package Alarms is

  type time_t is mod 2**32;

  type AlarmObserver_t is interface;
  
  type TimeoutObserver is interface and AlarmObserver_t;
  procedure Timeout_Callback(This : in out TimeoutObserver) is abstract; -- polymorphic operation

  type AnotherTimeoutObserver is interface and AlarmObserver_t;
  procedure AnotherTimeout_Callback(This : in out AnotherTimeoutObserver) is abstract; -- polymorphic operation

  type AlarmPublisher_t (<>) is tagged limited private;
  function fConstructor (capacity : in Positive) return AlarmPublisher_t;

private

  type AlarObserverAcc_t is access AlarmObserver_t'Class;

  type dummy_t is new TimeoutObserver and AnotherTimeoutObserver with null record;
  overriding procedure Timeout_Callback(This : in out dummy_t) is null;  -- local type override
  overriding procedure AnotherTimeout_Callback(This : in out dummy_t) is null;  -- local type override

  dummy : constant AlarObserverAcc_t := new dummy_t;

  type Node_t is limited
    record
      Observer : AlarObserverAcc_t := dummy;
      time : time_t := time_t'Last;
    end record;

  defaultNode : constant Node_t := Node_t' (Observer => dummy,
                                            time     => time_t'Last);

  type ObserverArray_t is array (Positive range <>) of Node_t;

  type AlarmPublisher_t (capacity : Positive) is tagged limited 
    record
      --Member "observers" has default initialisation because Node_t is initialised
      observers : ObserverArray_t (Positive'First .. capacity);
    end record;

end Alarms;

package body Alarms is

    function fConstructor (capacity : in Positive) return AlarmPublisher_t is
    begin
        return Obj : AlarmPublisher_t (capacity => capacity) do
            Null;
        end return;
    end fConstructor;

end Alarms;
```

```ada
with Alarms;

package ConcreteObserver is

  type ConcreteObserver_t is new 
        Alarms.TimeoutObserver 
    and Alarms.AnotherTimeoutObserver 
  with private;

  --Procedure evTimeout to be notified for an alarm expirancy.
  --Null implementation to let you compile
  overriding
  procedure Timeout_Callback (this : in out ConcreteObserver_t) is null;

  --Procedure evAnotherTimeout to be notified for another alarm expirancy
  --Null implementation to let you compile
  overriding
  procedure AnotherTimeout_Callback (this : in out ConcreteObserver_t) is null;

private

  type ConcreteObserver_t is new
        Alarms.TimeoutObserver 
    and Alarms.AnotherTimeoutObserver 
  with 
    record
      --Any attribute
      Null;
    end record;


end ConcreteObserver;
```

You can use Object.Operation notation to call Callback for your AlarmPublisher_t object.  EX:

```
for Node of Observers loop
    if Node.observer in TimeoutObserver'Class then
        TimeoutObserver'Class(Node.observer).Timout_Callback;
    end if;

    if Node.observer in AnotherTimeoutObserver'Class then
       AnotherTimeoutObserver'Class(Node.observer).AnotherTimeout_Callback;
    end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: That's my current implementation, the normal Observer pattern that uses no callbacks. The problem here is that the observer interface offers just one procedure to be implemented by concrete observers, and the Publisher knows only one subprogram to call the observers through the interface. With this implementation, the observers can't have more than one method to be notified. I was exploring something more flexible to let subscribers to subscribe adding the callback to the method they want to be notified

Comment: @Albatros23 You can do that with this method.  Can you update your question to include your new criteria and an example of the different callback setup you think this won't fix?  With the interfaces method you can do a couple of different things including just add multiple different callback options or use an interface hierarchy with each derived interface having separate callbacks and have your observers register just for the ones they implement.  Without more info and example in your question it will be hard to give you a good example though.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I've edited to provide more information, I hope it help. I think the compiler complains about the parameter of the named access-to-procedure "Callback_t" defined in Alarms package when I try to create an instance of that type pointing to a procedure of a derived class.

Comment: @Albatros23 Okie dokie, updated the answer to include different callbacks.  You can extend this to only register each callback separately, fire the separately, or do all at once.  Each individual object can choose which callback to implement by implementing the corresponding interface.

Comment: sorry for the delay on this answer. I didn't noticed that an interface can extend another interface! Thanks!